# Translation of "It will be a while before/until..."

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

When explaining that something won't happen soon, English uses expressions like:

> It will be a while until ...
>
> It will be a while before ...
>
> It will be a long time until ...
>
> It will be quite some time before ...
>
> etc.

What is the most natural translation of sentences like these into Spanish?

Answer (score 4):

> Tomará un tiempo hasta que ...
>
> Llevará un tiempo hasta que ...

The word "un" is sometimes  omitted here, or replaced by "algún", or "bastante", or "considerable", etc.

Answer (score 1):

> Pasará un tiempo hasta que ...
>
> Transcurirrá un tiempo antes que ...